# Rewrite the routes skip the controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to access the following path without the controller name

e.g. `SITE/about` `SITE/faq`

How to do it ?

### routes.rb

```
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/about'
  get 'welcome/brand'
  get 'welcome/product'
  get 'welcome/news'
  get 'welcome/faq'
  get 'welcome/download'
  get 'welcome/contact'
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a how you want the url to be and which controller and controller method to visit.

Example, in your **routes.rb**

```
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
```

This way, `example.com/about` will point to action `about` in `PagesController`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
scope '/', controller: 'welcome' do
  get :index
  get :about
  get :brand
  get :product
  get :news
  get :faq
  get :download
  get :contact
end
```

It will also allow you to forget about writing controller name in each line.